# Logo for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to show my plugin logo on the "Add Plugins" area inside of the wordpress admin area but I can't find how do that, I think this can be something similar to the image header for the plugin page but I can't find anything

The screenshot shows an example, three extension with their own logo and other with a default logo.

.![wordpress plugins area][1]

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/21/introducing-plugin-icons-in-the-plugin-installer/):

> Plugin icons are 128 pixels square. HiDPI (retina) icons are supported at 256 pixels square. Like banners, these go into your /assets directory and can be either a PNG or JPG. So just create assets/icon-128x128.(png|jpg) and/or assets/icon-256x256.(png|jpg) and you have an icon.
>
> You also have another option: SVG. Vectors are perfect for icons like
>   this, as they can be scaled to any size and the file itself is small.
>   For an SVG file, you simply need an assets/icon.svg file.
>
> We may implement SVG-to-images fallbacks in core for browsers that
>   don’t support them, so if you go the SVG route, I’d suggest also
>   turning your SVG into a PNG. (SVG takes precedence.)

In your repository you have to add a folder called `assets`, and inside the filder at least a file called `icon-128x128.png`, and you can add another one called `icon-256x256.png` for users with retina displays. Check the [repo for Akismet](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet?order=name) as an example.

Comment: Thanks, excellent information, any chance you can point me in the direction of the guidelines about the assets directory ?

Comment: @user3677392, on the [same blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/07/04/fun-with-high-dpi-displays/)

Comment: @user3677392, I updated the answer with more details.